# click event do not fire ans css not called when class and id given dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic, click

hi all i am declaring id and class when creating table dynamically as below i have bing using many function to make my click  event running but all in vein ,pls help me if anyone can?

This is my dynamic table with id and class i have to call css on "td" click and also click event should be fired

```
   var tableid=0;               
    // display table.......
        $('#page').append("<center> <table id='tables'  cellspacing='50px' style='margin-top:70px' >");
        for(var j=0;j<row;j++){          
                $('#tables').append("<tr class='row' id='row"+j+"' style='margin-bottom:50px'>");
                        for(var k=0;k<5;k++){
                                if(tableid<tablecount-1){
                                        $("#row"+j).append("<td id='"+tableid+"' class='button' width='150' height='150' background='images/green.png' align='center'>"+
                                                            "</td>");   
                                        tableid++;
                                    }
                        }//for ends.                    
                        $('#tables').append("</tr'>");
        }//for ends
        $('#page').append("</center> </table>");
```

i want to fire event individually for all td and on click i want to call function that pass my id as paramenter; i am using id unique for each "td"and the code commented below is the methods i tried to implement/get my click event fired and call my css running but all in vein,

```
/*Event.observe(window, 'load', function(){
            $('#TBL00001').observe('click', test());
            });             
            function test(){
                alert("click :)))");
            }
            $("'#"+tableCode[tableid]+"'").live(function() {
                    alert("Table"+tableCode[tableid]);
            });
            $("'#"+tableCode[tableid]+"'").click(function() {
                        alert("Table"+tableCode[tableid]);
            });

            $('#TBL00001').on( 'click', 'td', function() {
                        alert("Table"+tableCode[tableid]);});
            */
```

now i have also tried .delegate() which works but i cant pass id (unique)  for each td all

```
                $('.button').each(function(){
                $(this).click(function{
                    alert("hi");
                });
           });


              $("tr .row > td .button").each(function() { 
            var $this = $(this);
            alert("hi"+$this);
        }

         /*$("table").delegate($(this),"click",function(){
            alert($(this));
            printBill(tabid);
        });
```

Comment: HTML advice: Do not use `center` tag, it's deprecated. Also, you close the tags in wrong order.

Comment: thnx u keep in mind this advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('table').delegate('tr.row > td', 'click', function() {
    id = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

I´m not sure if I understand your question.

This code will execute on every td click, and the variable id will contain the td´s id.

Comment: I think we should better go with event delegation with on feature in jquery pls let me know your comment

Comment: @Ajaybeni Sure, I believe it´s time for me to get used with delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You should use on with event delegation

```
$("table").on("click",function(e){
alert(jquery(e.target).attr('id');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked Ids of tr in firebug?

assigning like this, can be wrong.

```
  id='"+tableid+"'
```

try this.

```
id="+tableid+"
```

Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is a condition `if(tableid<tablecount-1){` well I think you have not defiened `tablecount` anywhere, hence the condition is not working.

Secondly as mentioned above you can fetch each **ID** if td in the following way :-

```
$('td').click(function(){
   var tdId = $(this).attr('id');
   console.log(tdId); // You would get the Id of clicked td in teh consloe and now you can  use the variable **tdId** for your function.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its in your approach of creating a table. You should create the table in a way like this.

```
 $(function(){
var tableid=0;
var row = 5;

// display table.......
var theTable = $('<table />').attr('id', tableid);

for(var j = 0; j < row; j++){
    var theRow = $('<tr />').attr('id', 'row'+j).addClass('row');
    for(var k=0;k<5;k++){
        var theTd = $('<td />').addClass('button').html('test').click(function(){ alert('test') });
        theRow.append(theTd);
    }
    theTable.append(theRow);
}

$('#page').append(theTable);
    });
```